# Using link_to with routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My route:

```
  scope "/ajax" do
    resources :companies do
      resources :comments
    end
  end
```

So, `link_to company.title, company` generates such url: `/ajax/companies/1`

How to generate clear url **without the first `/ajax/` part?**
As a result i want to generate `companies/(:id) and companies/create and companies/edit/(:id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer is to remove the `scope '/ajax' do` line, but I have a feeling that is not what you are looking for. Maybe just put the resources line in there again outside of the scope block.

Is ajax a module? If so, just replace it with `scope :module => 'ajax' do`.

Comment: No module, usual `CompaniesController < ApplicationController`. I need it because of complicated ajax frontend. Is it possible to rewrite `link_to` method for my requirements?